Clarification on Criminal record question in job seeker visa application to Germany
I’m applying to Germany for a job seeker visa.
A Domestic assault case was filed against me in the US in 2018. I was arrested for 12 hours, then the case final disposition was dismissed and expunged (dismissed after attending anger management classes).
Should I answer yes or no for criminal record in the visa application?

What is the actual wording (in the visa application) of the question about which you are asking?

I belive this question belongs on Expatriates, not Travel.

Which state? Laws vary by state, some may still maintain a public or confidential record of the charge and its disposition even after expungement. Some states remove all records of an arrest and/or subsequent court case from the public record, and the individual may legally deny or fail to acknowledge ever having been arrested for or charged with any crime which has been expunged

Isn't the question “Sind Sie vorbestraft? Have you ever been convicted?”

On what a 'criminal record' is (and may contain) will depend on the country you are appling to. In Germany, a criminal record will not contain anything that a (final decision of a) judge has found you guilty of and where you have been sentenced to a punishment that is less than 3 months. Should you add this information to your application, assume that a German consulate official will come to the conclusion that your situation would not lead to an entry into a German criminal record.

Answering 'Yes' will not lead automatically to a refusal, but will be judged based on the given circumstances.

Remember that a German consulate official in the US will know that things work differently in the US than Germany.

As meantioned in my first comment, 'Yes' with  the given circumstances ('was arrested for 12 hours, then the case final disposition was dismissed and expunged (dismissed after attending anger management classes)') should lead to the conclusion that it is not a conviction under German law. Just because the US may, possibly, consider you a convicted felon, doesn't mean that Germany will do the same. My understanding of US law, only a jury (or when none is required - a judge) may actually convict someone of breaking the law.

From what you wrote, no court was involved - and thus, for Germany, no conviction exists.

@coco Are you running this page through some sort of automated translator? I followed your link and I do see “Sind Sie vorbestraft?” You can clearly answer “no” to that question.

In UK, taking a voluntary correction course (such as when caught speeding) is an alternative to receiving a conviction. That's the point – no conviction – not a criminal. In my example you don't have to inform the insurance company.

@coco I don't see how this makes a difference, dismissed is dismissed, you have not been convicted to any specific sentence but ultimately you'll have to decide for yourself. I would be very surprised if such data is shared between the US and Germany.

@WeatherVane *not a conviction .. correcting my comment on the above

@Relaxed thankyou for clarifying. it makes me feel little relaxed about applying to germany

Following the clarification in the comments, the question on the website you mentioned is “Sind Sie vorbestraft?” Using the dropdown on the page to switch to English changes it to “Have you ever been convicted?” This is also what I have seen on other German visa application forms.
“Do you have a criminal record?” is Google Chrome's translation of the original German but not the question you are being asked. It sounds more idiomatic but it is not as close to the German meaning as the official translation.
Based on your description, the answer to “Sind Sie vorbestraft? / Have you ever been convicted?” is clearly no. This is also in line with German practice where only actual convictions to more than 90 days in jail go in your criminal record, as described in a comment by Mark Johnson.
